# Php login form dont work using mamp dont load its only a white screen

Tags: php, html, css, mamp

> php are not loading.. when opening browser and heres my database
>   info:MySQL

The MySQL Database can be administered with phpMyAdmin.

To connect to the MySQL Server from your own scripts use the following connection parameters:

```
Host     localhost
Port     8889
User     root
Password root
```

Example:

`$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');`
or you can connect using an UNIX Socket:

```
Socket      /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
User        root
Password    root
```

Example:

```
$link = mysql_connect(
  ':/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
  'root',
  'root'
);
```

have some quite problems...

```
   <?php


$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";
$db = "test";

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password'".$password."' LIMIT 1";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if mysql_num_row($res) == 1) {
echo "You have succesfully logged in.";
exit ();
}   else {
echo "Invalid login info. Please return to the previous page.";
exit ();

    }
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Dark Login Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<style script="javascript">
<style type="text/css">
Body,p {
color: red;
}

.Button {
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #000000), color-stop(1, #ff0000) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100% );
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#79bbff    ', endColorstr='#378de5');
background-color:;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
border-top-left-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
border-top-right-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
text-indent:0;
border:0px solid #FF0000;
display:inline-block;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bold;
font-style:normal;
height:40px;
line-height:40px;
width:101px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #528ecc;
margin-right:0.3em;

}
.Button:hover {
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #000000), color-stop(1, #ff0000) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100% );
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#', endColorstr='#79bbff');
background-color:#;
}.Button:active {
position:relative;
top:1px;    
}</style>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="login.php">
<p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<center>
  <label for="login">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="login" value="name@example.com">
    </p>

    <p>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="4815162342">
 </p>   
<input class="Button" type="submit" value=Log In></a>
</center>       

<p class="forgot-password"><a href="forgotpassword.html">Forgot your password?</a></p>
</form>

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors you're getting? Try mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_error()); mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error()); for debugging

Comment: nothing its only a blank page

Comment: its still just a blank page..

Comment: You've turned on error reporting?

Comment: put ini_set('display_errors',1); @ the satrt of the php page.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection's port is not default MYSQL port..

use 
$link = mysql_connect('localhost:8889', 'root', 'root');
format to connect to server.

tutorial at.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

you SQL query has some problem,
its
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND **password'".$password."'** LIMIT 1";

but when you checking password, you forgotten to use '=' symbol. check that...

and

in 
**if mysql_num_row**($res) == 1) {
has missing '(' after if command

Comment: could i add you on skype so you can help me more further ? and you mean if (mysql_num_row($res) == 1) {

Comment: its still just blank page.

Comment: did you corrected  - password'".$password."' - to - password' = ".$password."' -

Comment: Okey i have saved it my file to login.php in html section i have <form method="post" action="login.php"> its the same name on the page and to go to the same ? dont get it now when i open my php page it still blank im wondering what it can be is it because i use php and html in same page ? i have no clue seriously also using mamp /local host to see php page